# Nodemon giving an issue

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemon

1. I installed `nodemon`.
2. I made changes to my code.
3. It is stuck at RESTARTING DUE TO CHANGES and doesn't restart the server.

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

[image: Screenshot is given.]

```
>>index.js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, world!');
})

app.get('./help', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Help Page!');
})

const port = 3000;
// const hostName = '127.0.0.1';

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});



>>package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "Sharjeel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the latest version of the nodemon. The previous or older version runs completely fine without making any issue i.e. nodemon@2.0.7.